# Wpf - BitmapImage data binding Singleton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, singleton

I have a singleton BitmapImage and I'm trying to bind it to my xaml view and i got :

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because it is owned by another thread
```

Here my code :

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(fullFilePath, UriKind.Absolute);
bitmap.EndInit();
MySingleton.Instance.image = bitmap;
```

My singleton :

```
private BitmapImage _image;
  public BitmapImage image
  {
     get { return _image; }
     set
     {
       _image = value;
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(image)));
     }
  }
```

And my xaml :

```
<Image Source="{Binding image, Source={x:Static module:MySingleton.Instance}}" Name="TestImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"></Image>
```

I tried `bitmap.Freeze();` but got the error:

> Freezable cannot be frozen

I don't know if it's meanless or not but I instanciate the bitmap in a websocket onmessage event.

Comment: Is `fullFilePath` a local file path?

Comment: @Clemens Nope an url, I tested the code without binding and with "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()" given by Lupu Silviu and it's working but I didn't found yet why the binding isn't working.

Comment: You cannot freeze the image probably because its cache option is `Default`. Try to set the `CacheOption` of the bitmap to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` before calling to `EndInit()`.

Comment: @dymanoid It's not the point anymore and yet I tried it because it can be a cool info but notpe I still got the error when calling Freeze

Comment: @dymanoid You can't freeze a BitmapImage while it is downloading image data. You can check its `IsDownloading` property and attach a handler for its `DownloadCompleted` event. When the download has completed, you may call Freeze().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has to be placed inside a Dispatcher.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
  //(your code here)
});
```

or

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
   //(your code here)
}));
```

Comment: Thanks ! I already saw this but I chose the wrong import :S. 
The code is working now but the image still not display, 
the Image is showing in a raw code without data binding tho.

Comment: Okay my bad the binding was working, I just failed my test xD.